# csv data file with "bytearray(...)" written in it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file with 2 columns such as:

```
1621324695.083352,bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x14G\x00\x00\n\xfe')
```

First value is a timestamp, and the other one the data.

My problem is when I try to read the file with `pd.read_csv()`, the `bytearray` values become strings. Is there a way to tell python it's already a `bytearray` value?

When I use the function `bytearray()` it outputs: `bytearray(bytearray(b'...'))`.

Answer (score 2):

In that file there is no bytearray, only its textual representation (plain text). We need to re-build the bytearray from it.

To convert a string like `"bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x14G\x00\x00\n\xfe')"` to a real bytearray the first idea is usually to use `eval`, but there are good reasons to avoid `eval` whenever possible.

We can simply extract the argument from the string, process the escape sequences (like `\x00` and `\n`) inside of it and pass the result to `bytearray()` in order to create the final object.

To extract the argument, use e.g. a regular expression. If the format is fixed, simple tools will do.

The escape sequence can be unescaped witht the `'unicode-escape'` decoder, but we have to convert from string to bytes. `latin1` is just a name for 8-bit ASCII, i.e. the 0-255 values a bytearray works with.

A simple demonstration:

```
inp = r"bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x14G\x00\x00\n\xfe')"
if inp.startswith("bytearray(b'") and inp.endswith("')"):
    arg = inp[12:-2]   # strip bytearray(b' and '), leave the string in between
    unesc = arg.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape')
    ba = bytearray(unesc, 'latin1')
    print(f"result: {ba!r}")
else:
    print("parse error!")
```

`ba` is a real bytearray and its representation `repr(ba)` equals to `inp`

Answer (score 0):

If you control the creation of the csv, it might be better to [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encode the bytearrays when writing them to the csv, and then decode in the dataframe.

This approach is generally better than stringifying binary objects, which generally require hacks to unstringify them when some other application consumes them.  Moreover, stringifying bytes will raise an exception if Python is executed with the [-bb](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-b) flag.  Base64 encoding is commonly used to encode binary data in textual environments.

First of all, let's make some binary data

```py
import base64
import csv
import io
import zlib

import pandas as pd

# Create some binary data
bas = [bytearray(zlib.compress(bytearray(w.encode('ascii')))) for w in ['hello', 'goodbye']]
print(bas)
```

Output:

```
[bytearray(b'x\x9c\xcbH\xcd\xc9\xc9\x07\x00\x06,\x02\x15'),
 bytearray(b'x\x9cK\xcf\xcfOI\xaaL\x05\x00\x0b\xaa\x02\xea')]
```

Now write it into an in-memory csv (or create a csv file, we're using a buffer here for convenience), applying base64 encoding

```
buf = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(buf)
writer.writerow(['id', 'binary_data'])
for i, ba in enumerate(bas):
    # Base64-encode the binary data and decode from bytes to str
    encoded = base64.b64encode(ba).decode('ascii')
    writer.writerow([i, encoded])
buf.seek(0)
```

Read the csv into a dataframe

```
# Read the csv into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(buf)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id           binary_data
0   0  eJzLSM3JyQcABiwCFQ==
1   1  eJxLz89PSapMBQALqgLq
```

Now decode from base64 to get the binary data

```py
df['binary_data'] = df['binary_data'].apply(lambda cell: base64.b64decode(cell))
print(df)
```

Output

```
   id                                       binary_data
0   0    b'x\x9c\xcbH\xcd\xc9\xc9\x07\x00\x06,\x02\x15'
1   1  b'x\x9cK\xcf\xcfOI\xaaL\x05\x00\x0b\xaa\x02\xea'
```

We get `bytes` rather than a `bytearray`, but that doesn't usually matter - the two types are mostly interchangeable.